# How to resample and round every index into nearest seconds?

Tags: python, database, pandas, dataframe

My data looks like (the datatype is Pandas DataFrame) :

```
price = 

time                bid
03:03:34.797000     116.02
03:03:34.797000     116.02
03:03:54.152000     116.02
03:03:54.169000     116.02
03:03:54.169000     116.02
03:07:36.899000     116.24
03:07:48.760000     116.24
03:07:48.760000     116.24
03:07:48.761000     116.24
```

I tried to resample the data into second level data and align every data into the nearest seconds no earlier than the original time. I expect the result to be:

```
03:04:00    116.02
03:05:00    NaN
03:06:00    NaN
03:07:00    NaN
03:08:00    116.24
```

and used

```
price.resample('Min').last()
```

However I got.

```
03:03:34.797000     116.02
03:04:34.797000     NaN
03:05:34.797000     NaN
03:06:34.797000     NaN
03:07:34.797000     116.24
```

Everything goes well except the alignment. Anyone could help me solve the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `floor`:

```
df.groupby(df.index.floor('Min')).last().resample('Min').asfreq()
```

Let's try for speed(need Pandas 0.21.0+):

```
df.set_axis(df.index.floor('Min'), axis=0, inplace=False)\
  .drop_duplicates().resample('Min').asfreq()
```

Output:

```
             bid
time            
03:03:00  116.02
03:04:00     NaN
03:05:00     NaN
03:06:00     NaN
03:07:00  116.24
```

Comment: Thanks. But the groupby could be slow right? I need to run this for about ~500M rows, is there any quick way to do this?

Comment: @MTANG I added another solution that doesn't use groupby and I see some speed improvement with this small dataset.

Comment: However I found that it gets even quicker if I manually add offsets to the index to align it into nearest minutes.

Comment: @MTANG would you post your solution?  This a great place for the SO community to learn from your situation.  Thank you.

Comment: @MTANG if this answer help you, would you consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top).  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
(df.groupby(df['time'].dt.round('1min') )['bid'].mean()).asfreq('Min')
Out[45]: 
time
2017-12-06 03:04:00    116.02
2017-12-06 03:05:00       NaN
2017-12-06 03:06:00       NaN
2017-12-06 03:07:00       NaN
2017-12-06 03:08:00    116.24
Freq: T, Name: bid, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried with this solution and it runs faster.

```
df = df.resample('Min').last()
offset_mc = df.index[0].microseconds
offset_sec = df.index[0].seconds % 60
if not (offset_mc == 0 and offset_sec == 0): df.index +=  pd.tslib.Timedelta(str(59-offset_sec)+'seconds '+str(1000000-offset_mc)+'microseconds')
```